# Background changes size when typing

Tags: android, eclipse

i added a background to my android activity , but when i click on an EdiText , the background's size changes any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your code to add the background to your activity?
Try adding

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`

entry inside the `<Activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`